# iCloud Display Set / NSUbiquitousDisplaySet in app's info.plist

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, icloud

I'm currently trying to get an iCloud-enabled app into the App store. The actual iCloud integration isn't the problem, it works wonderfully in testing.

I'm struggling with getting the app's binary to show up in the iCloud Display Set I created for it on iTunes Connect. The documentation is spotty and Googling around has only led back to Apple's documentation.

Anyone have any success with this? I've created a iCloud Display Set and in my app's info.plist I've defined the key NSUbiquitousDisplaySet with that Display Set ID as the value but when I submit the binary, it never shows up as an app linked to the iCloud Display set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunesConnect will attach your app to the display set after you submit the binary for review. I'm not sure if it will appear directly after submitting or only after Apple approved the app.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I'm not sure of. If it does just happen only after approval, I'll make your answer as correct (Currently still waiting for review)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had a space after `NSUbiquitousDisplaySet` in the Info.plist. If everything is correct, it will appear in the iCloud Display Set *as soon* as you upload the binary.